# Log in using Scrapy not working

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to log in to site using scrapy. I took an example site and checked. It is working for that site. Then i took another site and checked. Its not working. I just changed the urls and ran the code. But not working. What would be the problem?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quote'
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        token=response.xpath('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()

        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'csrf_token':token,'password':'foo','username':'foo'},callback=self.scape_home_page)

    def scape_home_page(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

This is working fine. THe other one is not.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class BucketsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'buckets'
    allowed_domains = ['http://collegekart.in/login']
    start_urls = ['http://collegekart.in/login/']

    def parse(self, response):
        token=response.xpath('//meta[@name="csrf-token"]/@content').extract_first()
        print(token)
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'csrf-token':token,'password':'*********','username':'**************'},callback=self.scape_home_page)

    def scape_home_page(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print("yes")
```

This is not working. The response is not opening in browser. Please suggest me some ways to solve this.

Comment: Please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `allowed_domains = ['http://collegekart.in/login']` please try changing it to `allowed_domains = ['collegekart.in']` the other response is probably getting filtered.

Comment: If i change that to 'collegekart.in', it is redirecting to that page, but it has to redirect to 'collegekart.in/users'. 'collegekart.in' is not a valid link. is there any way to modify this.

Comment: Problem solved. We have to replace the url in response.